# How do I use the Lookup expression and the IIF expression in SSRS?

Tags: reporting-services, expression, sql-server-2014, iif

I have researched and not been able to find the answer to my question.  My goal is to use the `Lookup` function in SSRS, which is currently performing as intended.  However, I have null values that are not present which I would represented as '0'.  It seems like I should be able to use the `Lookup` expression along with a `IIF` function.  However, I cannot find an example of this.  Any ideas how I can accomplish this? My `Lookup` expression is below.

```
=LookUp(Fields!SKU.Value,
Fields!ItemCode.Value, 
Fields!Store.Value, "DataSet3")
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd use `IsNothing` function to check if the  value is Null and wrap it in a `IIF` expression. Here is the [Microsoft reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/reporting-services/report-design/expression-examples-report-builder-and-ssrs?view=sql-server-2017) for different expressions.

```
=IIF
(
  IsNothing(LookUp(Fields!SKU.Value, Fields!ItemCode.Value, Fields!Store.Value, "DataSet3"))
, 0
, LookUp(Fields!SKU.Value, Fields!ItemCode.Value, Fields!Store.Value, "DataSet3")
)
```

Comment: This was 100 % perfect and exactly what I needed.  I will use this as a reference to further my knowledge in terms of SSRS Syntax.  Thank you very much for helping with the solution.

Comment: If my answer sorted you out, can you click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in?

Comment: Yes sir, I have completed this.  I apologize I wasn't aware of where to click to accomplish this.  Thank you again for your support.  If your feeling up for another challenge I posted another question re: SSRS.

Comment: No worries mate :)